# asp.net MVC4 multiple models in one view impossible

Tags: asp.net

So..I've got this trouble querying the database for info about two tables.... I've done everything seen in this page and other forums...finally gave up and give you my code if anyone can help!

The model (tried with List<>, IEnumerable<>, etc..)

```
 public class FotoViewModel
{
    public FOTOGRAFIA FOTOGRAFIA { get; set; }
    public DISENO DISENO { get; set; }

}
```

the Controller

```
public ActionResult FotoCat()
    {
        FotoViewModel model = new FotoViewModel();
        return View(model);

    }
```

and the view

```
@model IEnumerable<PBD_ArteGenero.Models.FotoViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<ul class="polaroids">
    <li>
        <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FOTOGRAFIA.URL_FOTOGRAFIA)" title="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DISENO.NOMBRE_DISENO)">
            <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FOTOGRAFIA.URL_FOTOGRAFIA)" alt="asd">   
        </a>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

}

as you can see my trouble is that i want to call URL_FOTOGRAFIA from FOTOGRAFIA and NOMBRE_DISENO from DISENO......

Comment: You are passing an empty model, what do you expect? You need to set the fields (typically load objects from database) in the controller method to be able to use them in the view.

Comment: that's the point, i've tried making some queries to the database but nothing seems to works....so mi question is how to fill this big model in the controller....

Answer (score 0):

Replace your controller action with something like this:

```
public ViewResult FotoCat()
{
    return View(yourContext.FotoViewModel.ToList());
}
```

I don't know the name of your Context class. Anyway, `yourContext` should have a similar declaration at the beginning of your controller class:

```
private PBD_ArteGeneroEntities yourContext = new PBD_ArteGeneroEntities();
```

Comment: i made this and now just throws "Invalid object name 'dbo.FotoViewModels'."